# Qt : How to get all the classes that are children of a specific class

Tags: c++, qt, introspection, moc

Qt's Meta Object system allows a lot of interesting introspection. But my problem is the following : let's suppose I have coded a `class MyClass : public QObject`. I want to have a button in my GUI to create an instance of `MyClass`. But I decide to create `MySubClass : public MyClass` and I create another button to create an instance of `MySubClass`.

Now a colleague also creates his own subclass. Is there a way to automatically find out all the classes that extend `MyClass` (and add automatically a relevant button)?

I can see some workaround like having an array of `MetaObject` so that I can call `QMetaObject::newInstance()` on each of them, but it requires me to add manually the subclass everytime a new sublass is added to the codebase.

Is there an automatic way to do it? If need be I can restrict myself to classes that implement a specific `Q_INTERFACE` if it makes any difference.

Comment: I ask this question because I know I can do it in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no automatic way to do it, because the classes are not registered anywhere - a `Q_OBJECT` macro only adds members directly to the class but doesn't register the class.

What you could do is add a project-wide define that modifies `Q_OBJECT` to add a factory registration via a member, e.g.:

```
// this declaration added to `Q_OBJECT`:
Factory::Registration q_obj_reg{this};
```

Given:

```
class Factory {
public:
  class Registration {
  public:
     template <typename T> Registration(T*);
     ...
  };
```

};

This would automagically register all `QObject` classes on first use at least.

Comment: I am about to be convinced, but then how does QMetaObject::newInstance() work then without registration?

Comment: I found out that there is indeed no magic, and this is why I had to use qRegisterMetaType(). So you are indeed correct and I am convinced